# Feign client throwing 401

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

I am trying to hit a **third party API** **(Running in a different server - Not my micro-service)** from my application **(running on my local machine)**. The API, when executed on the postman, works perfectly.

```bash
curl --location --request POST 'https://myserver.com' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
    --header 'Accept: application/json' \
    --data-urlencode 'client_id=12345****67890' \
    --data-urlencode 'client_secret=123456&&&&&5678**90' \
    --data-urlencode 'grant_type=abcd' \
    --data-urlencode 'token_format=jwt'
```

But when I tried through Feign it fails.

```java
@FeignClient( name = "test", url = "https://myserver.com", configuration = FeignSimpleEncoderConfig.class )
public interface AuthFeinClient {

    @PostMapping( value = "/uaa/oauth/token", consumes = "application/json" )
    @Headers( "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" )
    ResponseEntity<String> getAuthToken( @RequestBody Map<String, String> formData );
}
```

Now I am calling the interface method

```java
Map<String, String> formData = new HashMap<>();
formData.put("client_id", "12345****67890");
formData.put("client_secret", "123456&&&&&5678**90");
formData.put("grant_type", "abcd");
formData.put("token_format", "jwt");
    
ResponseEntity<String> authToken = feignClient.getAuthToken(formData);
```

I am sending the form data in a `map`. I also tried with `MultiValueMap` as well. But the same error is coming.

```
feign.FeignException$Unauthorized: [401] during [POST] to [https://oauth.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:8443/uaa/oauth/token] [AuthFeinClient#getAuthToken(Map)]: []
    at feign.FeignException.clientErrorStatus(FeignException.java:197) ~[feign-core-10.7.4.jar:na]
    at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:177) ~[feign-core-10.7.4.jar:na]
    at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:169) ~[feign-core-10.7.4.jar:na]
    at feign.codec.ErrorDecoder$Default.decode(ErrorDecoder.java:92) ~[feign-core-10.7.4.jar:na]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:156) ~[feign-core-10.7.4.jar:na]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:80) ~[feign-core-10.7.4.jar:na]
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:100) ~[feign-core-10.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy107.getAuthToken(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.highpeak.tlp.ybanqauthmanager.service.AuthManagerServiceImpl.generateAuthTokenAndSaveInRedis(AuthManagerServiceImpl.java:64) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.highpeak.tlp.ybanqauthmanager.controller.AuthController.getAuth(AuthController.java:28) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) [spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) [spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) [spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) [spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) [spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) [spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) [spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93) [spring-boot-actuator-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_232]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_232]
```

I also set up the encoder to send form data.

```java
@Configuration
public class FeignSimpleEncoderConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters> messageConverters;

    @Bean
    FormEncoder feignFormEncoder() {
        return new FormEncoder(new SpringEncoder(this.messageConverters));
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You have to use anottation `@EnableFeignClients` in your main class.

Comment: it is there. I have annotated

Comment: I think 401 indicates that the form data is not reachig the third paty as expected

Comment: Yes, it is the client id and client secret. They are not being injected in your request.

Comment: I am setting it in a map and sending.

Comment: Is it because I am trying to call a third part api which is not my microservice and is running in different server?

Comment: You can reproduce this error (401) using curl, if you remove the `--data-urlencode` fields from your command.

Comment: So what should I do to inject the form data? I am injecting as a `Map`?

Comment: Never used in my projects, but the relevante documentation is here. Look for `BasicAuth` https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem before. I could use the OkHttpClient or curl request, but not FeignClient. This is my solution, and it's work for me, I hope it worked for you, too.

```java
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass(Feign.class)
@AutoConfigureBefore(FeignAutoConfiguration.class)
public class FeignOkHttpConfig {
    @Bean
    public okhttp3.OkHttpClient okHttpClient(){
        return new okhttp3.OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectionPool(new ConnectionPool())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean({Client.class})
    public Client feignClient(okhttp3.OkHttpClient client) {
        return new feign.okhttp.OkHttpClient(client);
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean({ConnectionPool.class})
    public ConnectionPool httpClientConnectionPool(FeignHttpClientProperties httpClientProperties, OkHttpClientConnectionPoolFactory connectionPoolFactory) {
        Integer maxTotalConnections = httpClientProperties.getMaxConnections();
        Long timeToLive = httpClientProperties.getTimeToLive();
        TimeUnit ttlUnit = httpClientProperties.getTimeToLiveUnit();
        return connectionPoolFactory.create(maxTotalConnections, timeToLive, ttlUnit);
    }

    @Bean
    public OkHttpClient client(OkHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, ConnectionPool connectionPool, FeignHttpClientProperties httpClientProperties) {
        Boolean followRedirects = httpClientProperties.isFollowRedirects();
        Integer connectTimeout = httpClientProperties.getConnectionTimeout();
        Boolean disableSslValidation = httpClientProperties.isDisableSslValidation();
        return httpClientFactory.createBuilder(disableSslValidation)
                .connectTimeout((long)connectTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .followRedirects(followRedirects)
                .connectionPool(connectionPool)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Through my debugging, by default, FeignClient's default-Client is called to initiate a request, so we can force it to use OkHttpClient with the above configuration.

Finally, please forgive my English is not very good.
The more important is springboot config code.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding `consumes = APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE` on `@PostMapping()`?

full code would be:

```java
@FeignClient(
    name = "test",
    url = "https://myserver.com",
    configuration = FeignSimpleEncoderConfig.class,
    consumes = APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE
)
public interface AuthFeinClient {

    @PostMapping( value = "/uaa/oauth/token", consumes = "application/json" )
    @Headers( "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" )
    ResponseEntity<String> getAuthToken( @RequestBody Map<String, String> formData );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

My requests worked with curl, but didn't with the feignClient (Err 401).

```
@FeignClient(value = "authentication-service", url = "http://localhost:1234/api/users")//<--wrong, should be /api/user
public interface AuthenticationServiceClient {

@PostMapping(value = "/register")
SomeResponseType register(User user);
}
```

In my case I used "users" instead of "user" in my url (inside the FeignClient annotation), which caused a 401 instead of 404 because only the url with "user" was excluded from csrf-protection (defined in my Spring Security config).

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic();
        http.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/api/user/register"); //like here
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/user/register") //and here
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();

    }
```